# Use device serial number instead of PID in HL7?

Tags: hl7

We are developing a medical device which shall be connected to a *Patient Data Management Systems* (PDMS). The idea is to use HL7 messages to push measured data directly to the PDMS.

The device itself is too small to fit a convenient user interface to input the patient id. Is it possible in HL7 to transmit just the device serial number instead of the PID and let the PDMS make the connection between the device and the patient?

Comment: What kind of message type do you envision to use?

Comment: I was thinking of PRT-10 and/or PRT-20. (Or, perhaps but not what I would prefer, use the PV1.)

Comment: Those (PRT, PV1) are segments, not event types (e.g. ORU^R01). What kind of message are you thinking of?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Yes, I intend to use the message type ORU^R01 and send the measured data in the OBR / OBX segments. (Perhaps there are other/better alternatives?)

Comment: You could have a look at: https://www.ihe.net/Patient_Care_Devices/ and how they solve this. /PID/PID-3 in ORU is required. So to have a "valid" ORU you need patient identification. However, if changes to your PDMS are possible you may work around this (and use the PRT-segment alone).

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at that

Answer (score 0):

The device serial number should be in the PRT-10 field, not the PID segment.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I know how set up the PID segment, the question is if I can omit the PID and just use the PRT and let the PDMS handle the mapping of the device to a patient?
Or, is it a must to implement a way to set the patient id on the medical device?